# Display/hide control based on Flags enum value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I have a flags enum containing all Provinces in Canada. In my application I have a list of Checkbox where you can check which province  you want to see in the application. I'd like to bind pages from a TabPanel to this enum, so that if Ontario is not Selected i want to hide the tab.

```
<max:MaxTabControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
        <max:MaxTabItem FieldDescription="Enum:PayrollProvincesType.Federal">
            <ScrollViewer>

            </ScrollViewer>
        </max:MaxTabItem>

        <max:MaxTabItem FieldDescription="Enum:PayrollProvincesType.Quebec">

        </max:MaxTabItem> 
        <!-- more provinces here -->
    </max:MaxTabControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just grab a Visibility converter and bind to `IsChecked` of the relevant `CheckBox`

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Ontario"/>

<Object Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, 
                             ElementName=Ontario, 
                             Converter={StaticResource VisibilityBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using a backing list of booleans in the ViewModel, but this is much cleaner

Comment: And if I want to bind it directly on my Object? In the case I have don't have access to the Checkbox (it's in another form)

Comment: @PLAudet Then you'll need a public bool to bind to from the IsChecked of the box to the Visibility of the object like Gordon mentioned.